# Quarterfinals - Highest Voted Division - QotY Tournament

Tags: discussion

This week is our Quarterfinal round in the highest voted division for Sports SE's Question of the Year Tournament.

A few guidelines:

- One vote per user per matchup (denoted by [comment](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/701))
- Votes will be accepted between Feb 27 and Mar 5
- For any [ties](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703), both teams will move onto the next round
- Short comments to explain your vote are acceptable. For any extended discussion, go into [The Clubhouse](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/the-clubhouse)

[image: 2016 Sports SE Question of the Year Tournament]

Answer (score 2):

H2 - [Usage of unusual characters in sports shirts](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14313/usage-of-unusual-characters-in-sports-shirts)

vs.

H15 - [Athletes who have competed in the Olympics for more than one country](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14521/athletes-who-have-competed-in-the-olympics-for-more-than-one-country)

---

Comment "My vote is - H2" or "My vote is - H15."

Comment: My vote is - H2

Comment: My vote is - H2

Comment: My vote is - H2

Comment: My vote is - H15

Comment: My vote is - H2.

Answer (score 1):

H1 - [Why are professional athletes allowed to compete in the Olympic games?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14378/why-are-professional-athletes-allowed-to-compete-in-the-olympic-games)

vs.

H16 - [Did Adolf Hitler really snub Jesse Owens at the 1936 Olympics in Berlin?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14147/did-adolf-hitler-really-snub-jesse-owens-at-the-1936-olympics-in-berlin)

---

Comment "My vote is - H1" or "My vote is - H16."

Comment: My vote is - H16

Comment: My vote is - H16.

Comment: My vote is - H1

Comment: My vote is - H1

Comment: My vote is - H1.

Answer (score 1):

H3 - [What is the most match points saved by a tournament winner?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13093/what-is-the-most-match-points-saved-by-a-tournament-winner)

vs.

H14 - [What happens if a suspended player is used in match and the referee didn't notice](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13535/what-happens-if-a-suspended-player-is-used-in-match-and-the-referee-didnt-notic)

---

Comment "My vote is - H3" or "My vote is - H14."

Comment: My vote is - H3

Comment: My vote is - H14

Comment: My vote is - H14

Comment: My vote is - H14.

Answer (score 1):

H4 - [Were volleys considered unsportsmanlike in tennis?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12975/were-volleys-considered-unsportsmanlike-in-tennis)

vs.

H13 - [If you can't change an injured goalkeeper, what can you do?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14511/football-if-you-cant-change-an-injured-goalkeeper-what-can-you-do)

---

Comment "My vote is - H4" or "My vote is - H13."

Comment: My vote is - H13

Comment: My vote is - H4.

Comment: My vote is - H4

Comment: My vote is - H13

Comment: My vote is - H13.

Answer (score 1):

H5 - [What is the record for the most family members competing in the same Olympic Games?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/what-is-the-record-for-the-most-family-members-competing-in-the-same-olympic-gam)

vs.

H12 - [Theoretically, what is the maximum number of times any two English Premier League teams can play each other in a single season?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13007/theoretically-what-is-the-maximum-number-of-times-any-two-english-premier-leagu)

---

Comment "My vote is - H5" or "My vote is - H12."

Comment: My vote is - H5

Comment: My vote is - H5

Comment: My vote is - H12

Comment: My vote is - H5

Comment: My vote is - H5.

Answer (score 1):

H6 - [Why do all "combat" sports always award championship belts (vs. other physical objects)?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13264/why-do-all-combat-sports-always-award-championship-belts-vs-other-physical-o)

vs.

H11 - [1 yellow, 1 red & 1 yellow card](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12756/1-yellow-1-red-1-yellow-card)

---

Comment "My vote is - H6" or "My vote is - H11."

Comment: My vote is - H11.

Comment: My vote is - H11

Comment: My vote is - H11

Comment: My vote is - H6.

Answer (score 1):

H7 - [Are there any sports that started as a women's sport?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/is-there-any-sports-that-started-as-womens-sport)

vs.

H10 - [Does Vatican participate in any International sports?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13217/does-vatican-participate-in-any-international-sports)

---

Comment "My vote is - H7" or "My vote is - H10."

Comment: My vote is - H7

Comment: My vote is - H7

Comment: My vote is - H10

Comment: My vote is - H10

Comment: Abstention, no vote.

Answer (score 1):

H8 - [Is there a connection between serious injuries/deaths in boxing and having one's father in one's corner?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13588/is-there-a-connection-between-serious-injuries-deaths-in-boxing-and-having-ones)

vs.

H9 - [Why does the NFL use Roman numerals for Super Bowl numbering?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13079/why-does-the-nfl-use-roman-numerals-for-super-bowl-numbering)

---

Comment "My vote is - H8" or "My vote is - H9."

Comment: My vote is - H9.

Comment: My vote is - H9.

Comment: My vote is - H9

Comment: My vote is -  H9

Comment: My vote is - H8.