# Quarterfinals - Most Viewed Division - QotY Tournament

Tags: discussion

This week is our Quarterfinal round in the most viewed division for Sports SE's Question of the Year Tournament.

A few guidelines:

- One vote per user per matchup (denoted by [comment](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/701))
- Votes will be accepted between Mar 6 and Mar 12
- For any [ties](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703), both teams will move onto the next round
- Short comments to explain your vote are acceptable. For any extended discussion, go into [The Clubhouse](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/the-clubhouse)

Updated with the results of last week's round:
[image: 2016 Sports SE Question of the Year Tournament]

Answer (score 1):

V1 - [Why are two bronze medals awarded in judo at the Olympics?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14374/why-are-two-bronze-medals-awarded-in-judo-at-the-olympics)

vs.

V16 - [Can the captain change players' positions without permission from a coach or manager?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14991/can-the-captain-change-players-positions-without-permission-from-a-coach-or-man)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V1" or "My vote is - V16."

Comment: My vote is - V16

Comment: My vote is - V1

Comment: Abstention, no vote.

Comment: My vote is - V16

Answer (score 1):

V2 - [Why is field hockey played with water on the field?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14014/why-is-field-hockey-played-with-water-on-the-field)

vs.

V15 - [Why keep the left arm straight in golf but not in baseball batting?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14602/why-keep-the-left-arm-straight-in-golf-but-not-in-baseball-batting)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V2" or "My vote is - V15."

Comment: My vote is - V15

Comment: My vote is - V2

Comment: My vote is - V2.

Answer (score 1):

V3 - [Who are the football players that have scored in every minute of a football match?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/who-are-the-football-players-that-have-scored-in-every-minute-of-a-football-matc)

vs.

V14 - [Are there any sports other than American football that have a coach's challenge?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13498/are-there-any-sports-other-than-american-football-that-have-a-coachs-challenge)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V3" or "My vote is - V14."

Comment: My vote is - V14

Comment: My vote is - V3

Comment: My vote is - V3.

Answer (score 1):

V4 - [NFL teams beating the same team 3 times in a season](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15215/nfl-teams-beating-the-same-team-3-times-in-a-season)

vs.

V13 - [What happens when there are 2 turnovers on 1 play?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12937/what-happens-when-there-are-2-turnovers-on-1-play)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V4" or "My vote is - V13."

Comment: My vote is - V4

Comment: My vote is - V4

Comment: Abstention, no vote.

Answer (score 1):

V5 - [Why can't you hurdle someone in high school football?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13306/why-cant-you-hurdle-someone-in-high-school-football)

vs.

V12 - [Can a player get his second yellow card while being replaced? What happens then?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14711/can-a-player-get-his-second-yellow-card-while-being-replaced-what-happens-then)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V5" or "My vote is - V12."

Comment: My vote is - V5

Comment: My vote is - V12

Comment: My vote is - V12.

Comment: My vote is - V12

Answer (score 1):

V6 - [Are the gender differences in Olympic uniforms simply a style choice? Whose choice?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14381/are-the-gender-differences-in-olympic-uniforms-simply-a-style-choice-whose-choi)

vs.

V11 - [Are you allowed to fake a field goal or punt?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15068/are-you-allowed-to-fake-a-field-goal-or-punt)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V6" or "My vote is - V11."

Comment: My vote is - V6

Comment: My vote is - V6

Comment: Abstention, no vote.

Answer (score 1):

V7 - [Why do batsmen usually ask a fielder to tie their shoelaces?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/why-do-batsmen-usually-ask-a-fielder-to-tie-their-shoelaces)

vs.

V10 - [Why is Tom Brady's helmet different?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12925/why-is-tom-bradys-helmet-different)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V7" or "My vote is - V10."

Comment: My vote is - V7

Comment: My vote is - V7

Comment: My vote is - V10.

Answer (score 1):

V8 - [When can you get up again after falling on the ground?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13962/when-can-you-get-up-again-after-falling-on-the-ground)

vs.

V9 - [Is a goal scored if the goalkeeper, but not the ball, enters the goal?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/is-a-goal-scored-if-the-goalkeeper-but-not-the-ball-enters-the-goal)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V8" or "My vote is - V9."

Comment: My vote is - V8

Comment: My vote is - V8

Comment: My vote is - V8.