# Sweet 16 - QotY Tournament

Tags: discussion

This week is our Sweet 16(+) for Sports SE's Question of the Year Tournament. We saw several "upsets" in the quarterfinal rounds and even a tie. I look forward to this week's matchups!

A few guidelines:

- One vote per user per matchup (denoted by [comment](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/701))
- Votes will be accepted between Mar 13 and Mar 19
- For any [ties](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703), both teams will move onto the next round
- Short comments to explain your vote are acceptable. For any extended discussion, go into [The Clubhouse](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/the-clubhouse)

Updated with the results of last week's round:
[image: 2016 Sports SE Question of the Year Tournament]

Comment: Is this really the Elite 8, if there are 16+ "teams" in it?  :)

Comment: @BenMiller Ha! The "Elite 8...matchups." Yeah, there was an oversight somewhere on my part...

Answer (score 1):

H1 - [Why are professional athletes allowed to compete in the Olympic games?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14378/why-are-professional-athletes-allowed-to-compete-in-the-olympic-games)

vs.

H9 - [Why does the NFL use Roman numerals for Super Bowl numbering?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13079/why-does-the-nfl-use-roman-numerals-for-super-bowl-numbering)

---

Comment "My vote is - H1" or "My vote is - H9."

Comment: My vote is - H9

Comment: My vote is - H1.

Comment: My vote is - H1

Comment: My vote is - H9

Answer (score 1):

H5 - [What is the record for the most family members competing in the same Olympic Games?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/what-is-the-record-for-the-most-family-members-competing-in-the-same-olympic-gam)

vs.

H13 - [If you can't change an injured goalkeeper, what can you do?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14511/football-if-you-cant-change-an-injured-goalkeeper-what-can-you-do)

---

Comment "My vote is - H5" or "My vote is - H13."

Comment: My vote is - H5

Comment: Abstention in favour, no vote.

Comment: My vote is - H5

Answer (score 1):

H11 - [1 yellow, 1 red & 1 yellow card](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12756/1-yellow-1-red-1-yellow-card)

vs.

H14 - [What happens if a suspended player is used in match and the referee didn't notice](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13535/what-happens-if-a-suspended-player-is-used-in-match-and-the-referee-didnt-notic)

---

Comment "My vote is - H11" or "My vote is - H14."

Comment: My vote is - H11

Comment: My vote is - H14.

Comment: My vote is - H14

Comment: My vote is - H14

Answer (score 1):

H2 - [Usage of unusual characters in sports shirts](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14313/usage-of-unusual-characters-in-sports-shirts)

vs.

H7* - [Are there any sports that started as a women's sport?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/is-there-any-sports-that-started-as-womens-sport)

vs.

H10* - [Does Vatican participate in any International sports?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13217/does-vatican-participate-in-any-international-sports)

---

Comment "My vote is - H2",  "My vote is - H7" or "My vote is - H10."

<sub>*tied in its previous round</sub>

Comment: My vote is - H7

Comment: My vote is - H7.

Comment: My vote is - H2

Comment: My vote is - H2

Answer (score 1):

V8 - [When can you get up again after falling on the ground?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13962/when-can-you-get-up-again-after-falling-on-the-ground)

vs.

V16 - [Can the captain change players' positions without permission from a coach or manager?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14991/can-the-captain-change-players-positions-without-permission-from-a-coach-or-man)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V8" or "My vote is - V16."

Comment: My vote is - V16.

Comment: My vote is - V8

Comment: My vote is - V8

Comment: My vote is - V16

Answer (score 1):

V4 - [NFL teams beating the same team 3 times in a season](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15215/nfl-teams-beating-the-same-team-3-times-in-a-season)

vs.

V12 - [Can a player get his second yellow card while being replaced? What happens then?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14711/can-a-player-get-his-second-yellow-card-while-being-replaced-what-happens-then)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V4" or "My vote is - V12."

Comment: My vote is - V12

Comment: My vote is - V12.

Comment: My vote is - V4

Answer (score 1):

V3 - [Who are the football players that have scored in every minute of a football match?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/who-are-the-football-players-that-have-scored-in-every-minute-of-a-football-matc)

vs.

V6 - [Are the gender differences in Olympic uniforms simply a style choice? Whose choice?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14381/are-the-gender-differences-in-olympic-uniforms-simply-a-style-choice-whose-choi)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V3" or "My vote is - V6."

Comment: My vote is - V3

Comment: My vote is - V6.

Comment: My vote is - V6

Comment: My vote is - V3

Answer (score 1):

V2 - [Why is field hockey played with water on the field?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14014/why-is-field-hockey-played-with-water-on-the-field)

vs.

V7 - [Why do batsmen usually ask a fielder to tie their shoelaces?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/why-do-batsmen-usually-ask-a-fielder-to-tie-their-shoelaces)

---

Comment: "My vote is - V2" or "My vote is - V7."

Comment: My vote is - V2

Comment: My vote is - V2.

Comment: My vote is - V7

Comment: My vote is - V2