# Final 4 - QotY tournament

Tags: discussion

This week is our Final 4(+) for Sports SE's Question of the Year Tournament. This week, we have a five way matchup and a three way matchup due to ties.

A few guidelines:

- One vote per user per matchup (denoted by [comment](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/701))
- Votes will be accepted between Mar 27 and Apr 2
- For any [ties](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703), both teams will move onto the next round
- Short comments to explain your vote are acceptable. For any extended discussion, go into [The Clubhouse](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/the-clubhouse)

Updated with the results of last week's round:
[image: 2016 Sports SE QotY Tournament]

Comment: Final Four Sale Week ~ Buy Four, Get Four Free!!

Answer (score 2):

H1* - [Why are professional athletes allowed to compete in the Olympic games?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14378/why-are-professional-athletes-allowed-to-compete-in-the-olympic-games)

vs.

H5* - [What is the record for the most family members competing in the same Olympic Games?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/what-is-the-record-for-the-most-family-members-competing-in-the-same-olympic-gam)

vs.

H7* - [Are there any sports that started as a women's sport?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/is-there-any-sports-that-started-as-womens-sport)

vs.

H9* - [Why does the NFL use Roman numerals for Super Bowl numbering?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13079/why-does-the-nfl-use-roman-numerals-for-super-bowl-numbering)

vs.

H14* - [What happens if a suspended player is used in match and the referee didn't notice](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13535/what-happens-if-a-suspended-player-is-used-in-match-and-the-referee-didnt-notic)

<sub>*tied in its previous round</sub>

---

Comment "My vote is - H1", "My vote is - H5", "My vote is - H7", "My vote is - H9" or "My vote is - H14."

Comment: My vote is - H14.

Comment: My vote is - H5

Comment: My vote is - H9

Comment: My vote is - H7.

Answer (score 2):

V2 - [Why is field hockey played with water on the field?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14014/why-is-field-hockey-played-with-water-on-the-field)

vs.

V12* - [Can a player get his second yellow card while being replaced? What happens then?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14711/can-a-player-get-his-second-yellow-card-while-being-replaced-what-happens-then)

vs.

V16* - [Can the captain change players' positions without permission from a coach or manager?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14991/can-the-captain-change-players-positions-without-permission-from-a-coach-or-man)

<sub>*tied in its previous round</sub>

---

Comment: "My vote is - V2", "My vote is - V12" or "My vote is - V16."

Comment: My vote is - V16.

Comment: My vote is - V2

Comment: My vote is - V2.

Comment: My vote is - V2.